# How to remove request limit in ufw / iptables

Tags: iptables, ufw

I have a flask script that handles incoming requests. There can be a lot of such requests in a short period of time, however, if I understand correctly, then initially the firewall has some kind of restriction on incoming requests for a certain period of time. Because if I send let's say 10 requests within ~10 seconds, the script only processes 4 of them, but it's not about the script, because. I tested it on my PC, so the server itself does not miss a large number of requests in a short period of time, how can I fix this? I will be very grateful for your help.

iptables -t nat -xvnL

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

iptables -vxnL

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 891 packets, 37562 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       1       40 fail2ban-HESTIA  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083
   28477  1704349 fail2ban-MAIL  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587,110,995,143,993
      89     6570 fail2ban-FTP  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
   20733  2248126 fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
  101755 178516849 fail2ban-RECIDIVE  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 1:65535
   74771 177128413 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
     156     9360 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       *IP_OF_VPS*        0.0.0.0/0
     234    14040 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0
     856    65655 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    2012   105744 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
      12      612 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21,12000:12100
       9      525 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
       1       40 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
     181    10514 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587
       5      200 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995
      13      612 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 143,993
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8778
      12      584 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   39941  3658019 ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   39941  3658019 ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   39760  3596357 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    4565   196858 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    4565   196858 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    4565   196858 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x02 #conn src/0 > 50
       0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x17/0x02 #conn src/0 > 150

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   88838 12259629 ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   88838 12259629 ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2650   184151 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2650   184151 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2650   184151 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2650   184151 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-FTP (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      89     6570 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-HESTIA (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       1       40 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-MAIL (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   24380  1457827 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-RECIDIVE (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1308    78480 REJECT     all  --  *      *       87.246.7.75          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    9707   582380 REJECT     all  --  *      *       5.34.207.58          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    1722   103320 REJECT     all  --  *      *       212.70.149.66        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    1649    98940 REJECT     all  --  *      *       212.70.149.18        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    7883   472960 REJECT     all  --  *      *       5.34.207.219         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   79486 177180769 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      24     1840 REJECT     all  --  *      *       81.29.214.123        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      24     1848 REJECT     all  --  *      *       72.167.224.135       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      24     1844 REJECT     all  --  *      *       43.154.47.14         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   16631  1950958 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain hestia (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      19     1482 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
       9     2061 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
       1       40 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
       6      272 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
      20     5440 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    6301   607388 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     891    37562 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     309    19969 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      19     9722 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
      19     9722 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
    7256   654765 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
    7256   654765 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     315    24476 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     315    27676 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     740   496082 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    6752   945190 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
     309    19969 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      19     9722 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW AUDIT INVALID] "
      19     9722 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     715    32296 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
     193     6176 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    6348   616293 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
       0        0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 30/min burst 50
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    6356   616683 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      16      960 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
     293    19009 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */
       9      520 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5000
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       *IP_OF_FIRST_VPS*       0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:25
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:465
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:993
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:143

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: We would have to see your entire iptables rule set to be able to help. If your iptables rule set is generated by UFW, which is just a front end for iptables, then it can be very difficult to read and follow. Do `sudo iptables -vxnL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL` and edit your question adding the outputs.

Comment: you can check it now

Comment: I can't figure it out. There is some rate limiting, but it doesn't seem to have been hit. Could you try your test again and then look for log entries in `/var/log/syslog` and look at the packets counters for `sudo iptables -xvnL` for a clue. Also try disabling fail2ban, just as a test to answer the question: Is it fail2ban or is it UFW?

Comment: Could this be an issue with nginx ? Because the work is arranged in such a way that initially requests go to the first server and after that are sent to the second one (where the request handler is located) Because nginx is also installed on the first server

Comment: There is no incoming rate limit on ports 80 or 443 so it is either fail2ban or something else.

Comment: ok, ill check it. So far I'm setting up nginx and gunicorn using the manual from digitalocean and nothing works for me )))